# Necesito hacer que la posicion del header y el nav sea fixed sin alterar la posicion del contenido que le sigue

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código de CSS para que el `header` y el `nav` se quede en el mismo lugar cuando le de scroll a la página, pero el contenido que le sigue se posiciona en la parte superior de la página quedando debajo del `header` y el `nav` oculto. Necesito acomodarlo y que se posicione después del `nav`.

```
     header{
     position: fixed;
     margin-top: -10px;
     background-color: gray;
     margin-left: -8PX;
     padding: 1px;
     margin-top: -41PX;
     padding-left: 15px;
     color: white;
     width: 100%;

}

    nav{
    background: #2D787B; 
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los elementos `fixed` son retirados del flujo normal del documento y se muestran como un contexto separado, por lo que *no ocupan lugar* en la secuencia de elementos. Una opción es poner un elemento vacío que ocupe dicho espacio y que sea parte del flujo normal de la pagina. Esto funciona si los elementos tienen una altura conocida y si es al principio de la pagina.

Ejemplo simplificado: el `<header>` y el `<nav>` suman en total 70 pixels CSS de altura por lo que el "relleno" también debe ocupar es alto.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px; left: 0; right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}

#relleno {
  height: 70px;  
}
```

```html
<header>Este es el header</header>
<nav>Este es el NAV</nav>
<div id="relleno"></div>
<p>Este es el elemento que siguie</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
<p>y otro mas</p>
```

Comment: que se hace cuando colocas un glyphicon ese si se sigue posicionando encima del header